# Crear base de datos en SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

estoy transicionando de mysql a SQL en un proyecto de python y tengo un problema. Con un simple script estoy intentando crear una base de datos nueva. Pero me da error, copié el código de un tutorial agregando solamente el comando de crear la base de datos. No sé donde está mi error, si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias.

Aquí dejo el ejemplo para que puedan reproducirlo.

```
import pyodbc


try:
    conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=PROYECTO\SQLEXPRESS; UID=PROYECTO\Baelca; Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor1=conn.cursor()
    print("conexion exitosa") 
    cursor1.execute("CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS Lista_datos_Baelca  ")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print("Base de datos creada")
        
    
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error")
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola carlos! Dos cosas, primero, no me tienta mucho crear mi propio sql server para hacer la prueba. Segundo, tal y como lo copiaste del tutorial, el except te imprime solamente "error". Si quitas el try-except obtendrás el verdadero mensaje de error. Cuando lo obtengas, podrías copiarlo en la pregunta por favor?

Comment: La opción de `IF NOT EXISTS`  no está disponible para crear bases de datos en SQL Server.

Comment: @DanteS. Si, el problema es de sintaxis. Lo reemplacé por `CREATE DATABASE Lista_datos_baelca` y me arroja: CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.